# Will changing my Windows Login Password affect our MS SQL server / connection?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, sql-server

The Password of the Admin account we used to login to our Windows 2008 R2 server is expiring will it affect our MS SQL server / connections, i fear it might because our SQL server management studio uses windows authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the account is tied to any services or is programmed into any applications, they will need to be updated as well. Otherwise your services will fail due to a logon failure because of the non-matching passwords.

In regards to the management studio, it has no impact as the user account is given permissions to connect to the database instance. The Windows Authentication method that SSMS uses pulls your windows login information (your user ID and not password) and checks for the previously mentioned permission for the database.